# The best way to collect the Java-8 Stream to Guava ImmutableList

Tags: java, java-8, guava, java-stream

I want to get a stream into an immutable list. What is the difference between following approaches and which one is better from performance perspective?

1. `collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf));`
2. `ImmutableList.copyOf( stream.iterator() );`
3. `collect( Collector.of(
                   ImmutableList.Builder<Path>::new,
                   ImmutableList.Builder<Path>::add,
                   (l, r) -> l.addAll(r.build()),
                   ImmutableList.Builder<Path>::build)  );`

A few more parameters for performance or efficiency,

1. There may be many entries in the list/collection.
2. What if I want the set sorted, using the intermediate operation `".sorted()"` with a custom comparator.
3. consequently, what if I add `.parallel()` to the stream

Comment: Related: [How can I collect a Java 8 stream into a Guava ImmutableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013250/how-can-i-collect-a-java-8-stream-into-a-guava-immutablecollection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect 1) to be the most efficient: going via extra builders seems less readable and unlikely to win over normal `toList()`, and copying from the iterator discards sizing information.

(But Guava is working on adding support for Java 8 things like this, which you might just wait for.)

Comment: thanks, could you please elaborate "copying from the iterator discards sizing information"

Comment: A `Stream.iterator()` doesn't know its size.  Going via `toList()` gets you a sized list.  It could be argued either way, though -- you're losing the sizing information when you build the `List`, but you have it back when you copy it to the `ImmutableList`.

Answer (score 3):

For system performance, you need to measure it.

For programming performance, use the clearest way.  From appearance alone, I like the second one best, and I see no obvious inefficiency there.