# How can I collect a Java 8 stream into a Guava ImmutableCollection?

Tags: java-8, guava, java-stream

I would like to do the following:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but in a way that the resulting list is an implementation of Guava's `ImmutableList`.

I know I could do

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> immutableList = ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
```

but I would like to collect to it directly. I've tried

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ImmutableList::of));
```

but it threw an exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection.add(ImmutableCollection.java:96)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `toImmutableList()` method in the accepted answer of Alexis is now included in  [Guava 21](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21) and can be used as:

```
ImmutableList<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7)
    .boxed()
    .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
```

**Edit:** Removed `@Beta` from `ImmutableList.toImmutableList` along with other frequently used APIs in [Release 27.1](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v27.1) ([6242bdd](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/6242bdd27bfa7a2223548a082c25a8ef97a951)).

Comment: The method marked as   @Beta. So it's not reccomended apriory by docs ?

Comment: Still `@Beta` as of Guava 26.0.

Comment: For the sake of perspective, Google kept Gmail under a beta tag between 2004 and 2009 which was already a fairly stable, mature product at launch in 2004.  Google is pretty reluctant to promote products from Beta status in general.  Almost to the point of comedy.

Answer (score 71):

This is where the `collectingAndThen` collector is useful:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7).boxed()
                .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf));
```

It applies the transformation to the `List` you just built; resulting in an `ImmutableList`.

---

Or you could directly collect into the `Builder` and call `build()` at the end:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7)
                .collect(Builder<Integer>::new, Builder<Integer>::add, (builder1, builder2) -> builder1.addAll(builder2.build()))
                .build();
```

If this option is a bit-verbose to you and you want to use it in many places, you can create your own collector:

```
class ImmutableListCollector<T> implements Collector<T, Builder<T>, ImmutableList<T>> {
    @Override
    public Supplier<Builder<T>> supplier() {
        return Builder::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Builder<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return (b, e) -> b.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Builder<T>> combiner() {
        return (b1, b2) -> b1.addAll(b2.build());
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Builder<T>, ImmutableList<T>> finisher() {
        return Builder::build;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return ImmutableSet.of();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7)
                              .boxed()
                              .collect(new ImmutableListCollector<>());
```

---

Just in case the link disappears in the comments; my second approach could be defined in a static utility method that simply uses `Collector.of`. It's simpler than creating your own `Collector` class.

```
public static <T> Collector<T, Builder<T>, ImmutableList<T>> toImmutableList() {
    return Collector.of(Builder<T>::new, Builder<T>::add, (l, r) -> l.addAll(r.build()), Builder<T>::build);
}
```

and the usage:

```
 List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7)
                               .boxed()
                               .collect(toImmutableList());
```

Comment: This still creates an intermediate list, doesn't it? I would like to avoid that. Could the `ImmutableList.Builder` be of any help?

Comment: @Zoltán You could accumulate the values in the builder directly (see edit) and then call `build()`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. It seems that this is currently being addressed: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1582, there's also a nice example here (a lot like what you suggested): https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/9734167

Comment: @Zoltán Ah yes; good finds; it simply wraps the second alternative into utility methods. A bit better than defining your own `Collector` class :-)

Comment: Reference types could be `ImmutableList<Integer>` (instead of `List<Integer>`).

Answer (score 19):

While not a direct answer to my question (it does not use collectors), this is a fairly elegant approach which doesn't use intermediate collections:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = IntStream.range(0, 7).boxed();
List<Integer> list = ImmutableList.copyOf(stream.iterator());
```

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1582#c3).

Answer (score 7):

BTW: since JDK 10 it can be done in pure Java:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 7)
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

Also `toUnmodifiableSet` and `toUnmodifiableMap` available.

Inside collector it was done via `List.of(list.toArray())`

Comment: This is not _exactly_ true, since `ImmutableCollections.List12` and `ImmutableCollections.ListN` != Guava's `ImmutableList`. From a practical perspective you are mostly correct, but it would still make sense to mention this nuance in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, there's a reasonable way to do this in Guava without Java 8:

```
ImmutableSortedSet<Integer> set = ContiguousSet.create(
    Range.closedOpen(0, 7), DiscreteDomain.integers());
ImmutableList<Integer> list = set.asList();
```

If you don't actually need the `List` semantics and can just use a `NavigableSet`, that's even better since a `ContiguousSet` doesn't have to actually store all the elements in it (just the `Range` and `DiscreteDomain`).