# Java 8 collector for Guava immutable collections?

Tags: java, guava, java-stream

I really like Java 8 streams and Guava's immutable collections, but I can't figure out how to use the two together.

For example, how do I implement a Java 8 [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) that gathers stream results into an [ImmutableMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html)?

Bonus points: I'd like to be able to provide key/value mappers, similar to how [Collectors.toMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) works.

Comment: This link can help- http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/12/immutable-list-collector-in-java-8/

Comment: yes this has got http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/29/java-8-collector-for-gauvas-linkedhashmultimap/  thanks for Arijit

Comment: @Arjit this is a great step in the right direction, but I'm still trying to get the key/value mappers to work.

Comment: Use this link - http://blog.comsysto.com/2014/11/12/java-8-collectors-for-guava-collections/

Comment: @Arjit Thank you. I independently came up with a similar implementation through trial and error (posted below).

Comment: Strongly related, but not in the related sidebar yet: [How can I collect a Java 8 stream into a Guava ImmutableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013250/how-can-i-collect-a-java-8-stream-into-a-guava-immutablecollection)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since version 21, you can

```
.collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet())
.collect(ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap())
.collect(Maps.toImmutableEnumMap())
.collect(Sets.toImmutableEnumSet())
.collect(Tables.toTable())
.collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList())
.collect(Multimaps.toMultimap(...))
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update**: I found an implementation that seems to cover all Guava collections at https://github.com/yanaga/guava-stream and attempted to improve upon it in my own library at https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/guava-jdk8/

I'm leaving the previous answer below, for historical reasons.

---

Holy #@!( I got it!

This implementation works for any Multimap (mutable or immutable) whereas [shmosel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30635782/14731) focuses on immutable implementations. That said, the latter might be more efficient for the immutable case (I don't use a builder).

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics;
import org.bitbucket.cowwoc.preconditions.Preconditions;

/**
 * A Stream collector that returns a Multimap.
 * <p>
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 * @param <T> the type of the input elements
 * @param <K> the type of keys stored in the map
 * @param <V> the type of values stored in the map
 * @param <R> the output type of the collector
 */
public final class MultimapCollector<T, K, V, R extends Multimap<K, V>>
    implements Collector<T, Multimap<K, V>, R>
{
    private final Supplier<Multimap<K, V>> mapSupplier;
    private final Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper;
    private final Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper;
    private final Function<Multimap<K, V>, R> resultMapper;

    /**
     * Creates a new MultimapCollector.
     * <p>
     * @param mapSupplier  a function which returns a new, empty {@code Multimap} into which intermediate results will be
     *                     inserted
     * @param keyMapper    a function that transforms the map keys
     * @param valueMapper  a function that transforms the map values
     * @param resultMapper a function that transforms the intermediate {@code Multimap} into the final result
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     */
    public MultimapCollector(Supplier<Multimap<K, V>> mapSupplier,
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper,
        Function<Multimap<K, V>, R> resultMapper)
    {
        Preconditions.requireThat(mapSupplier, "mapSupplier").isNotNull();
        Preconditions.requireThat(keyMapper, "keyMapper").isNotNull();
        Preconditions.requireThat(valueMapper, "valueMapper").isNotNull();
        Preconditions.requireThat(resultMapper, "resultMapper").isNotNull();

        this.mapSupplier = mapSupplier;
        this.keyMapper = keyMapper;
        this.valueMapper = valueMapper;
        this.resultMapper = resultMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Multimap<K, V>> supplier()
    {
        return mapSupplier;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Multimap<K, V>, T> accumulator()
    {
        return (map, entry) ->
        {
            K key = keyMapper.apply(entry);
            if (key == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("keyMapper(" + entry + ") returned null");
            V value = valueMapper.apply(entry);
            if (value == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("keyMapper(" + entry + ") returned null");
            map.put(key, value);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Multimap<K, V>> combiner()
    {
        return (left, right) ->
        {
            left.putAll(right);
            return left;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Multimap<K, V>, R> finisher()
    {
        return resultMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics()
    {
        return EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class);
    }
}
```

[...]

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

/**
 * Stream collectors for Guava collections.
 * <p>
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class GuavaCollectors
{
    /**
     * Returns a {@code Collector} that accumulates elements into a {@code Multimap}.
     * <p>
     * @param <T>          the type of the input elements
     * @param <K>          the type of the map keys
     * @param <V>          the type of the map values
     * @param <R>          the output type of the collector
     * @param mapSupplier  a function which returns a new, empty {@code Multimap} into which intermediate results will be
     *                     inserted
     * @param keyMapper    a function that transforms the map keys
     * @param valueMapper  a function that transforms the map values
     * @param resultMapper a function that transforms the intermediate {@code Multimap} into the final result
     * @return a {@code Collector} which collects elements into a {@code Multimap} whose keys and values are the result of
     *         applying mapping functions to the input elements
     */
    public static <T, K, V, R extends Multimap<K, V>> Collector<T, ?, R> toMultimap(
        Supplier<Multimap<K, V>> mapSupplier,
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper,
        Function<Multimap<K, V>, R> resultMapper)
    {
        return new MultimapCollector<>(mapSupplier, keyMapper, valueMapper, resultMapper);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Multimap<Integer, Double> input = HashMultimap.create();
        input.put(10, 20.0);
        input.put(10, 25.0);
        input.put(50, 60.0);
        System.out.println("input: " + input);
        ImmutableMultimap<Integer, Double> output = input.entries().stream().collect(
            GuavaCollectors.toMultimap(HashMultimap::create,
                entry -> entry.getKey() + 1, entry -> entry.getValue() - 1,
                ImmutableMultimap::copyOf));
        System.out.println("output: " + output);
    }
}
```

main() outputs:

```
input: {10=[20.0, 25.0], 50=[60.0]}
output: {51=[59.0], 11=[24.0, 19.0]}
```

### Resources

- [Arjit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850925/arjit) provided an excellent resource demonstrating how to implement Collectors for other Guava collections: http://blog.comsysto.com/2014/11/12/java-8-collectors-for-guava-collections/

Comment: +1 for posting your solution as a reusable library we can add as a simple Maven dependency! :-)  This looks like just the stop-gap solution I was looking for until [Guava 21](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/ZRmDJnAq9T0) comes out with this built in (mid 2016)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that will support several `ImmutableMultimap` implementations. Note that the first method is private since it requires an unsafe cast.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T, K, V, M extends ImmutableMultimap<K, V>> Collector<T, ?, M> toImmutableMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyFunction,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueFunction,
        Supplier<? extends ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, V>> builderSupplier) {

    return Collector.of(
            builderSupplier,
            (builder, element) -> builder.put(keyFunction.apply(element), valueFunction.apply(element)),
            (left, right) -> {
                left.putAll(right.build());
                return left;
            },
            builder -> (M)builder.build());
}

public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMultimap<K, V>> toImmutableMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyFunction,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueFunction) {
    return toImmutableMultimap(keyFunction, valueFunction, ImmutableMultimap::builder);
}

public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableListMultimap<K, V>> toImmutableListMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyFunction,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueFunction) {
    return toImmutableMultimap(keyFunction, valueFunction, ImmutableListMultimap::builder);
}

public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableSetMultimap<K, V>> toImmutableSetMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyFunction,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueFunction) {
    return toImmutableMultimap(keyFunction, valueFunction, ImmutableSetMultimap::builder);
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but it's limited to immutable implementations due to the use of `ImmutableMultimap.Builder`. It doesn't seem to be possible to provide a single Collector that will do the right thing for both mutable and immutable types. My answer supports both types, but it does not use a `Builder` so it might be less efficient for immutable collections.

Comment: @Gili, the question made it clear that you were looking for immutable collectors. Your answer doesn't support immutable types per se; it relies on the assumption that a mutable result can be subsequently copied to an immutable collection. As far as performance is concerned, my approach should be more efficient for sequential streams, whereas using a mutable accumulator would probably be preferable for parallel streams.

Answer (score 3):

For your example, you can use Guava's toImmutableMap() collector. E.g.

```
import static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap;

ImmutableMap<String, ZipCode> zipCodeForName =
    people.stream()
        .collect(
            toImmutableMap(Person::getName, p -> p.getAddress().getZipCode()));

ImmutableMap<String, Person> personForName =
    people.stream()
        .collect(
            toImmutableMap(Person::getName, p -> p));
```

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41674118/852336) has the rest of the Guava immutable collectors APIs

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't answer specifically the question, it's noteworthy to mention that this simple pattern can help everyone building Guava's immutable collections from streams without having the need for `Collector`s (as their implementations are rather hard to make).

```
Stream<T> stream = ...

ImmutableXxx<T> collection = ImmutableXxx.copyOf(stream.iterator());
```

Comment: That won't support any custom mapping or grouping functions that are standard in other collectors.