# Java - Are there any Stream Collectors that return ImmutableMap?

Tags: java-8, guava

I find myself wanting a variant of `Collectors.toMap` which returns an `ImmutableMap`, such that I can do:

```
ImmutableMap result = list.stream().collect(MyCollectors.toImmutableMap(
    tuple -> tuple._1(), tuple -> tuple._2());
```

(where `tuple` in this particular example is a Scala `Tuple2`)

I've [just learned](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/ZRmDJnAq9T0) that such a method will be coming with Java-8 support in Guava 21 (yay!) but that sounds a good 6 months away. Does anyone know of any existing libraries (etc) which might implement this today?

`ImmutableMap` is not strictly required but seems the best choice as I require: lookup by key, and retaining original iteration order. Immutability is always preferred too.

Note that `FluentIterable.toMap(Function)` is not sufficient because I need both a key-mapping function as well as a value-mapping function.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't see anything on the internet. Searching "guava java 8 collector" in a popular search engine returns a lot of directly usable code, including results directly in the Guava projects (as issues).

Comment: We provided `collectingAndThen()` for this purpose.

Comment: The answers in the question on `ImmutableMultimap` indeed answer my immediate questions. However none of the solutions there or that I've now found around the web seem to contain a perfect set of functions to handle `ImmutableMap` - they lack the ability to merge-duplicate-keys and/or don't throw `IllegalStateException` (following the convention set by `Collectors`)

Comment: Since Guava 21 there is built-in [ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#toImmutableMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071018/852336) for an example of how to use Guava's toImmutableMap() collector.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't need to write an anonymous class for this collector. You can use `Collector.of` instead:

```
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K,V>> toImmutableMap(
            Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
            Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {
    return Collector.of(
               ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>::new,
               (b, e) -> b.put(keyMapper.apply(e), valueMapper.apply(e)),
               (b1, b2) -> b1.putAll(b2.build()),
               ImmutableMap.Builder::build);
}
```

Or if you don't mind collecting the results into a mutable map first and then copy the data into an immutable map, you can use the built-in `toMap` collector combined with `collectingAndThen`:

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> result = 
     list.stream()
         .collect(collectingAndThen(
             toMap(
                 tuple -> tuple._1(), 
                 tuple -> tuple._2()),
             ImmutableMap::copyOf));
```

Comment: Perfect :-)  I didn't think to look into the interface itself. I definitely prefer the `Collector.of` form as this will become a utility function with unknown future use (and tracking down sources of memory churn can be difficult later.)

Comment: Guava now provides Collectors for their collection types, e.g. [`ImmutableList.toImmutableMap()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/2909a996047e575cdac02ea1c06a93a9419271cf/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java#L65-L82).

Comment: If you don't want to use Guava, you can do the same with  Map<String, String> result = 
     list.stream()
         .collect(collectingAndThen(
             toMap(
                 tuple -> tuple._1(), 
                 tuple -> tuple._2()),
             [Collections::unmodifiableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-)));

Comment: You should indicate that the second approach does not maintain the original iteration order as requested in the question.

Comment: I preferred `ImmutableMap::<K, V>builder` instead of `ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>::new`

Comment: If you are going to use a terminal operator than why not just wrap with `Collections.unmodifiableMap(...);`. There's really no need to have a specific Collector.

Comment: Re comments suggesting unmodifiableMap: there are many compelling benefits to using [ImmutableCollections](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) as provided by Guava, including *treating these like interfaces*. Our team strongly frowns upon any use of unmodifiable collections these days; if you can't soundly reason about your code locally (e.g. "might the wrapped collection be changed by code elsewhere?") it really impedes your work. We even only permit the JDK's List.of (etc) in unit tests: Guava's are just better.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find such a library of collectors yet, I'm sharing my first crack at the specific one I've needed. No bells or whistles here! (Such as handling or merging duplicate keys.)

Please feel free to suggest improvements.

```
/**
 * A variant of {@link Collectors#toMap(Function, Function)} for immutable maps.
 * <p>
 * Note this variant throws {@link IllegalArgumentException} upon duplicate keys, rather than
 * {@link IllegalStateException}
 * 
 * @param <T> type of the input elements
 * @param <K> output type of the key mapping function
 * @param <V> output type of the value mapping function
 * @param keyMapper  a mapping function to produce keys
 * @param valueMapper a mapping function to produce values
 * 
 * @return a {@code Collector} which collects elements into a {@code Map} whose keys and values
 *         are the result of applying mapping functions to the input elements
 *         
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException upon duplicate keys
 */
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K,V>> toImmutableMap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {
    return new Collector<T, ImmutableMap.Builder<K,V>, ImmutableMap<K,V>>() {

        public Supplier<Builder<K, V>> supplier() {
            return ImmutableMap.Builder::new;
        }

        public BiConsumer<Builder<K, V>, T> accumulator() {
            return (builder, element) -> {
                K key = keyMapper.apply(element);
                V value = valueMapper.apply(element);
                builder.put(key, value);
            };
        }

        public BinaryOperator<Builder<K, V>> combiner() {
            return (b1, b2) -> {
                b1.putAll(b2.build());
                return b1;
            };
        }

        public Function<Builder<K, V>, ImmutableMap<K, V>> finisher() {
            return builder -> builder.build();
        }

        public Set<Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return ImmutableSet.of();
        }
    };
}
```