# Java 8 Collector for Guava's ImmutableListMultimap<String,T>

Tags: java, java-8, guava, collectors

Looking for an easy way to collect collection of `KeyAndValues having fields  - String  and List<T>` to `ImmutableListMultimap<String,T>`?
 Tried to do something like,

```
 Collector.of(
          ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::new,
          ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<String,List<T>>::putAll,
          (b1, b2) -> b1.putAll(b2.build()),
          (builder) -> builder.build());
```

`putAll` takes `Key`, `List<T>`. I am not sure how to achieve this in combiner.

EDIT :

```
 @Value(staticConstructor = "of")
 private static class KeyAndValues<T> {

    private final String key;
    private final List<T> values;
}
```

Comment: What is `KeyToValues`?

Comment: Added KeyAndValues class.

Comment: @Holger : Doesn't work, getting compiler error  : 

The method of(ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::new, ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<String, List<T>>::putAll, (<no type> b1, <no type> b2) -> {}, (<no type> builder) -> {}) is undefined for the type Collector

Comment: Oh, well. I got confused because you said you have problems with the *combiner* whereas it’s the *accumulator* that doesn’t work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 collector for Guava immutable collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634608/java-8-collector-for-guava-immutable-collections)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the methods available on `KeyAndValues<T>`, but how about this?

```
  public static <T> Collector<KeyAndValues<T>,
                              ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<String, T>, 
                              ImmutableListMultimap<String, T>> toImmutableMultimap()
  {
    return Collector.of(
        ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::new,
        (b, kav) -> b.putAll(kav.getKey(), kav.getValues()),
        (builder1, builder2) -> builder1.putAll(builder2.build()),
        (builder) -> builder.build());
  }
```

Alternatively, if you would prefer to hide the accumulator details, you can use something like this:

```
public static <T> Collector<KeyAndValues<T>,
                            ?,
                            ImmutableListMultimap<String, T>> toImmutableMultimap()
{
  return Collector.of(
    ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<String, T>::new,
    (b, kav) -> b.putAll(kav.getKey(), kav.getValues()),
    (builder1, builder2) -> builder1.putAll(builder2.build()),
    (builder) -> builder.build());
}
```