# Concatenate elements of two sets with delimiter using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, guava, java-stream

I have two sets say:

```
ImmutableSet<String> firstSet = ImmutableSet.of("1","2","3");
ImmutableSet<String> secondSet = ImmutableSet.of("a","b","c");
```

I would like to get a set which consists of elements of the first set concatenated with each of the elements of the second, along with a delimiter i.e the output should be:

```
ImmutableSet<String> thirdSet = ImmutableSet.of("1.a","1.b","1.c","2.a","2.b","2.c","2.c","3.a","3.b","3.c");
```

(Here "." is my delimiter)

I had initially thought I would be able to do this by streaming the first set and applying `Collectors.joining()` on the elements of the second, but that won't solve my need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using guava. In that case you can simply use `Sets.cartesianProduct` method

```
Set<List<String>> cartesianProduct = Sets.cartesianProduct(firstSet,secondSet);
for (List<String> pairs : cartesianProduct) {
    System.out.println(pairs.get(0) + "." + pairs.get(1));
}
```

Output:

```
1.a
1.b
1.c
2.a
2.b
2.c
3.a
3.b
3.c
```

If you want to collect it in `ImmutableSet<String>` you can use

```
ImmutableSet<String> product = ImmutableSet.copyOf(
        cartesianProduct.stream()
                        .map(pairs -> pairs.get(0) + "." + pairs.get(1))
                        .toArray(String[]::new)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

> I had initially thought I would be able to do this by streaming the
>   first set and applying Collectors.joining() on the elements of the
>   second, but that won't solve my need.

What you can do is stream the first set, and flat map each element with all the elements of the second set.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

...

ImmutableSet<String> thirdSet = 
    firstSet.stream()
            .flatMap(s1 -> secondSet.stream().map(s2 -> s1+"."+s2))
            .collect(collectingAndThen(toSet(), ImmutableSet::copyOf));
```

If you directly want to collect into an `ImmutableSet`, you create a custom collector using the `ImmutableSet`'s builder (see also [How can I collect a Java 8 stream into a Guava ImmutableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013250/how-can-i-collect-a-java-8-stream-into-a-guava-immutablecollection/29013372#29013372)).